# What's the Vim option to make indentation matches source file?

Tags: indentation

I just started at a new company where apparently there is no standardization on tab/space setting at all. Everything goes.

That culture is not going to change. What I want to do is make Vim matches the spacing used in the file open, so that at least we have consistency.

Ex: open a file, looks like all lines use `softtab` with `shiftwidth=2`, so automatically set tab to 2 spaces.

What option could achieve this?

If I set `autoindent`, enter key works for new line. But tab key would still use the global Vim setting.

Comment: If it's "everything goes" just use what works best for you and reformat any file you touch. Any serious VCS or diff tool can ignore whitespace changes. And they probably won't even notice :)

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question or does the answer address the question? Is so maybe could you accept the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to install [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) that guess the indentation settings of the file and adapt the Vim configuration accordingly.